# Nested classes and the implicit this pointer

Tags: c++, class, templates, nested

I have a template class, and inside there is a nested class. My question is how to make the nested class have a reference to the class it is nested inside?

For example, the next array class

```
template< typename TYPE >
class Array
{
private:

    class ArrayProxy
    {
    public:

        ArrayProxy( Array< TYPE >& arrayObject, UnsignedInteger64bits entryIndex );

    private:

        Array< TYPE >& m_arrayObject;
        UnsignedInteger64bits m_entryIndex;
    };

};
```

Now to construct the ArrayProxy object, the next call is used within some method of the class Array:

```
ArrayProxy Array< TYPE >::DoSomething()
{
    return ( ArrayProxy( *this, entryIndex ) );
}
```

This does not compile.

My confusion starts with what happens to the implicit this pointer, because the nested ArrayProxy, should have the same location of the outer class no?? and does the data member of a nested class makes the total class data larger, or it is just if an instance of the nested class created??

Comment: The outer and inner class are unrelated objects at runtime.

Comment: So the only point of a private nested class is to make sure that only the outer class can create it??

Comment: Merely yes, that's the only point.

Comment: The question is still how to send a reference of the outer class to an inner class!!!

Comment: You can provide a constructor parameter for the inner class for instance.